# Segue destination returns SWRevealViewController instead of UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I am preparing the values from func prepare. The problem is the application crashes because the destination returns SWRevealViewController instead of UIViewController. I am using SWRevealViewController on the storyboard.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    if (segue.identifier == "Main") {
        let view = (segue.destination as! Main)
        view.expired_login = self.expired_login
    }
}
```

It crashes on the let view line. Here is the message

```
Could not cast value of type 'SWRevealViewController' (0x10afa72a8) to 'JetWayTrade.Main' (0x10afac038).
```

Is there a way to get the Main so that I can set its properties? Here is the storyboard image

[image]

Comment: Mistaken segue connection / identifier ?

Comment: @vadian added an image of my storyboard

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you will want to cast the destination view controller as SWRevealViewController:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    if (segue.identifier == "Main") {
        let view = (segue.destination as! SWRevealViewController)
        view.expired_login = self.expired_login
    }
}
```

If you are expecting your Main view controller to be the destination then you will have to check that your segue names are set correctly in your storyboard.